# XGBoost evaluation metric unbalanced data - custom eval metric

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost

I have built a model using the xgboost package (in R), my data is unbalanced (5000 positives vs 95000 negatives), with a binary classification output (0,1).

I have performed cross validation with the evaluation metric `AUC` Area under the ROC curve which I now believe to be wrong since this is better used for balanced data sets.

I analyse the final results of the model using the Area Under the Precision Recal curve (AUPRC) and the Matthews Correlation Coefficient (MCC), however I now believe that I should have been evaluating the cross validation models with the AUPRC and MCC also and completely forget about the AUROC.

I cannot find much in the literature which uses CV with the evaluation metric of AUPRC and MCC.

I just want to make sure that I am thinking correctly and that my previous evaluation method is wrong and the AUPRC / MCC would be a better way to go.

Comment: It is incorrect that AUC has any issue with class balance.  AUC is insensitive to class balance, being the probability that the model scores a positively labeled class higher than a negatively labeled class.  You should also consider evaluating **model** performance with log-loss, which, being based on probabilities, is also insensitive to class balance issues.  It's important to seperate evaluating your **model** from evaluating your **decision rule**, these are different concerns.

Comment: Two questions: Are you suggesting that I I drop the evaluation using the AUC in favour of the log-loss evaulation? I am also a little unsure on the **decision rule** part. Is it refering to the decision rule of where to put the cut-off threshold?

Comment: This all depends on your application.  What are you building the model for?  Are you trying to build a decision rule, that needs to assign classes to new data points, or are the predicted probabilities sufficient for your purposes?  Are you more interested in ranking?  By evaluating your model with AUC, you are essentially saying that your dominant concern is how well your model ranks the data.  The answers to these types of questions governs how you should evaluate your model.  If you don't know, a very good default is log loss, since this ensures that your probabilities are accurate.

Comment: The model that I am building is to correctly fraud or people who are likely to go bankrupt (loan applications). So minimising Type 1 error is important (but both type 1 and 2 are important). The predicted probabilities are sufficient for my purpose and not interested in ranking the results which is why I think the AUPRC and MCC is more suitable.

Comment: If the predicted probabilities are sufficient, then you're not building a decision rule, so there is no concept of type one error.  If you'd like to ensure that the predicted probabilities are well calibrated to your data, then evaluating and comparing competing models on the basis of log loss is the way to go.  You may also want to stratify your data when evaluating to make sure that your model is not just predicting well on some class off applicants (i.e. a model that does well on adults, but is crap on college students).

Comment: Note that by drawing something like a PR curve, you're drawing out how the model would preform as a decision rule over an entire range of thresholds.  If you have no intention to set a threshold and use the model as a decision rule, than these kinds of evaluations are inappropriate for the application.

Comment: What I obtain from the model is predicted probabilities and from this I say that if >= 0.50 then assign a 1 do not give a loan and if < 0.5 assign a 0, give a loan. So the I am interested in the predicted probabilites because I can then change the threshold to minimise the type 1 and 2 errors.

Comment: Please, please, please don't use 0.5 as a default threshold.  This is almost always wrong.  If you intend to do this, you NEED to tune the threshold of your model based on your business objectives.  The correct way to do this is to estimate the costs to your business of false positives and false negatives, and then use those to set a correct classification threshold.  There is really no justification for using 0.5 as a default threshold in practice.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the advise, just to let you know the objective of this model, its not a model for a business its for an academic paper. You actually answered a previous question of mine that I had regarding my "imbalanced data" you mentioned that it is not (I agree with you and the fact that better predictors should lead to better predictive accuracy). My point being is that I have 11 carefully selected variables (from the literature) for the model (I know that its not optimal but its the best I can do). So I used `scale_pos_weight =  (negative_class) / sum(positive_class)` which...

Comment: significantly improves my type 1 error score at a slight cost of type 2 which I can live with since not giving a loan to somebody who will not default on that loan loses the company "potential" money in opportunity cost, whereas giving a loan to a bad client loses money directly.

Comment: I still don't agree with that, but if it's common practice in your community than I don't really get to have any influence over that : )  I think it's much better practice to fit on the data you have, and then carefully pick a threshold that meets the needs of your decision rule.  In any case, boosting should provide you with a well calibrated probability model, and if you set class weights you're implicitly balancing the data, so the 0.5 threshold should be "good enough".

Comment: Thanks for clearing up that worry! Its a PhD paper (in Economics) so one day I will have to defend the decisions that I make so I am trying to cover all the issues I run into. Machine Learning hasn´t been really applied too much in Economics so I am trying to figure most things out for myself. (Link to previous post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345372/decision-trees-gradient-boosting-and-normality-of-predictors )

Comment: So just to clear up, what would you do in such a situation: For cross validation, report in the paper (for the in-sample-test data) the log-loss and the AUC scores (including the AUPRC and MCC?) and finally the final results, sensitivity, specificity, AUC, AUPRC, MCC etc. on the out-of-sample test data?

Comment: Yah.  I'd probably report the cross validated log-loss for all the models I considered.  And then I would highlight whicever metrics of model performance supported the point I was trying to make with the model.  If you're interested in getting good estimates of the effect of some features (i.e. exactly how they influence the predicted probabilitiy), then I'd focus on the log loss.  I would also include some model calibration plots, and partial dependency plots of whichever variables I though most important for my research.

Answer (score 4):

I feel you are mixing few things:

1. 1:20 is not exactly a class imbalanced data. Classification algorithms work well with this ration also. If you still feel so, you can oversample your positive class or undersample negative class.
2. AUROC generally to compare different models. Like one from logistic and other from Xgboost.( It also ensures robustness of models), Generally AUROC is not used for model accuracy/ getting cut-off values.
3. Logloss/ misclassification rate/ F1 score/ MCC any of these can be used based on your requirement of classification. If you are predicted cancer , then you might not want to miss any patient and might be Ok to false positive, then focus should be on recall. f1 gives balance of precision and recall. Log loss is used (Log Loss heavily penaltises classifiers that are confident about an incorrect classification) when you don't want to have false positive. These links might help.

https://machinelearningmastery.com/classification-accuracy-is-not-enough-more-performance-measures-you-can-use/

https://www.r-bloggers.com/making-sense-of-logarithmic-loss/

https://towardsdatascience.com/evaluation-metrics-for-classification-409568938a7d